# Clone a git repository from a historial point in time

Tags: git

I'm developing a Rails app and using git. I decided to tryout a new gem, and created a git commit prior to any changes. To implement the gem involved removing some of my own code.

When I added the gem and made some other changes, I realised it would have been nice to have the earlier version of the app running, so I could compare side-by-side.

I solved the issue by rolling back git, copying the file tree and then re-applying the changes related to the new gem. That is I did the following:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
$ git clean -f -d
```

Is it possible to create a clone of a (local) git repository from one of the historical savepoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming "historical savepoints" are equivalent to commit times, as file-specific timestamps are not recorded by default, the checkout command's syntax appears to be:

git checkout *branch*@{*timediff*}

As in `git checkout master@{1 day ago}`, alternatively, you can use `git log` to isolate your commit ID and check it out with git checkout master *commitId*.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `git checkout <commit hash>`?

After executing this git will show a message something like this:

> Note: moving to ''  which isn't a local branch If you
>   want to create a new branch from this checkout, you may do so (now or
>   later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:   git
>   checkout -b  HEAD is now at 4553c14...

Comment: Thanks Aziz I will check that option out.